# Dunnetts test to compare control group with treatment groups

Tags: r

One way anova returned significant result. So, I want to go for Dunnetts test to compare the means of control (Method D) with treatment groups. Would someone help me do this on R as I am new to it. Here is my data:

```
mydata <- tibble(
  score = c(14,12,10,10,9,6,5,17,15,12,9,9,7,7,14,11,10,10,8,7,7,8,6,5,4,2,2,2), 
  method = as.factor(paste0("Method ", rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=7)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I read in the data:

```
mydata <- tibble(
  score = c(14,12,10,10,9,6,5,17,15,12,9,9,7,7,14,11,10,10,8,7,7,8,6,5,4,2,2,2), 
  method = as.factor(paste0("Method ", rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=7))
))
```

Next, if you want comparisons in relation to `Method D`, you should make that the first level of the factor:

```
mydata$method <- relevel(mydata$method, "Method D")
```

Next, estimate the ANOVA:

```
a <- aov(score ~ method, data=mydata)
```

Finally, using the `multcomp` package, you can generate the general linear hypothesis test that gives you the appropriate test:

```
library(multcomp)
g <- glht(a, linfct = mcp(method = "Dunnett"))
summary(g)

# 
# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts
# Fit: aov(formula = score ~ method, data = mydata)
# 
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# Method A - Method D == 0    5.286      1.630   3.243  0.00940 **
# Method B - Method D == 0    6.714      1.630   4.120  0.00116 **
# Method C - Method D == 0    5.429      1.630   3.331  0.00761 **
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DaveArmstrong. Means a lot.